# Prevent Jupyter screen from jumps down after cell evaluation

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Whenever i evaluate a cell (Shift+Enter) jupyter moves the screen down so that the output is shown, assuming the cell is to big to fit on the screen entirely.
I find this feature rather annoying as it jumps so fast that i sometimes lose track where i just was when debugging.

Is there a way to modify this behavior or to disable automated screen adjustments entirely?

I use a standard jupyter installation without any modifications.

> The version of the notebook server is: 5.2.0
> The server is running on this version of Python:
> Python 3.5.4rc1 (default, Jul 25 2017, 08:53:34)
> [GCC 6.4.0 20170704]

> Current Kernel Information:
> Python 3.5.4rc1 (default, Jul 25 2017, 08:53:34)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The `Shift+Enter` command is `run cell, select cell below`, so if you are debugging a cell this is probably not what you want. If you use `Ctrl + Enter`, that is just `run cell` and should not move your cell cursor.

This may be what is causing your issue, as jumping to the next cell would also show you your output, misleading you on the cause of your issue. Using `Ctrl + Enter` in my 5.2 notebook does not move my screen position at all.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to change "Run" button to work like this?

Comment: Shift Enter is ergonomically more convenient (Mac Air 11") than Ctrl Entr as it can be done with just one hand typing.  Is there a way to swap the two behaviours?

Comment: Macos Turns out that in version 6.4.0, (macos 11.5.1), `Cmd + Enter` behaves the same as `Ctrl + Enter`

Comment: @ShpielMeister Open Settings -> Keyboard shortcuts, search "Notebook: Execute Cell" and modify as needed.